# helm install qliksense | secrets already exists

Tags: kubernetes

I am pretty new to kubernetes. I run a kubernetes cluster on EKS (AWS).
When installing [QlikSense](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/June2019/Subsystems/PlanningQlikSenseDeployments/Content/Sense_Deployment/Preparing-Qlik-Sense-multi-cloud-Efe.htm) on kubernetes I receive the following error.

command:

```
helm install -n qliksense qlik/qliksense -f values.yaml
```

error:

```
Error: release qliksense failed: secrets "qliksense-nats-secret" already exists
```

Any idea how to solve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using Helm v2.14.3 and it worked for me, however I was installing in a cluster running on Docker for Mac.  Here are some more detailed steps...

1. Uninstall...

   ```
   helm delete --purge qliksense
   ```
2. Download the old Helm version v2.14.3 and overwrite existing local helm and tiller applications from [this link](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.14.3).
3. Re-initialize helm which will update version of tiller in the cluster

   ```
   helm init --force-upgrade --upgrade
   ```
4. Verify that helm and tiller are 2.14.3

   ```
   helm version
   ```
5. Try to install again.